# Facing problem with Regex Inside Sed Command

Tags: sed

Suppose I run the following commands:

```
export STR="abcdef.ghijkl.mnopqr.stuvwy.log"
echo $STR | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'
```

I am getting the following result:

```
abcdef.ghijkl.mnopqr.stuvwy
```

I do not understand the above result.

Comment: In addition to the answers here: `echo $STR` mangles your string, you're lucky here that it doesn't contain any special characters and so escapes unscathed. **Always put double quotes around substitutions**: `echo "$STR"`. This can still mangle an initial `-`; it's best to use `printf '%s\n' "$STR"`, or here [use shell string operations](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17956/18019#18019) and avoid these difficulties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sed pattern `\.[^.]*$` has only one match to the original string: `.log`.

Details:

- `\.` match only a dot character.
- `[^.]` matches any character different from `.`
- `[^.]*` matches any sequence of characters different from `.`
- `$` matches the end of line.

So here the final `.log` is the only match (`.stuvwy.log` is not a match because it contains an internal dot). `sed` will substitute this by the empty string as requested by the command `s/\.[^.]*$//`. Therefore you end up with:

```
abcdef.ghijkl.mnopqr.stuvwy
```

Comment: I thought as '.' matches any character except newline, so [^.] would mean matching only newline.

If that is not the case, then I agree with your explanation.

Comment: @nvarun: `\.` matches dot, and `.` matches anything. As for newlines, they are handled in a special way. The pattern is matched separately against each line, so it's unusual to use `\n` in sed commands.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `sed` you can use the shell's built-in pattern replacement. This is actually faster, not having to call an external program.

`${VAR%.*}` will remove the match of the glob pattern `.*` from the **end** of the string in `$VAR`. Remember it's a glob and not regex, so a `.` means a literal ".".

```
$ foo=aaa.bbbb.2011.log
$ echo ${foo%.*}
aaa.bbbb.2011
```

See [*Shell-Parameter-Expansion*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the BASH man page for more information.

Answer (score 2):

`s/\.[^.]*$//` == Substitute the first part of the string (because there's no `g` option at the end to match all occurrences) which starts with a dot (`\.`), followed by zero or more (`*`) characters which are not dots (`[^.]`), placed at the end of the string (`$`), with the empty string (`//`).